# Created an app, want to start using it as a library project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've got a complete, feature complete app, however i'd like to begin using it as a library project and make simply different versions of it with different images etc..

this project references action bar sherlock and seems to throw a dex class error that both are using sherlock when i reference it in the new project.

Am i supposed to remove the sherlock dependency from the original project and set it on the new one? that seemed to not work either.

I've look over no end of library project guides but none mention the use of ABS or similar?

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can go about this.

Firstly, make sure you have the Android Support Library.  You can include this in your project and all your library projects if you want PROVIDING IT IS THE SAME VERSION OF THE SUPPORT LIBRARY IN EACH CASE (in your case the ABS version of the support library). If you end up with different versions then you will get a message on logcat:

> Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but
>   not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at
>   this time).

However, it is probably more sensible to use just one version of the support library and to add it to just your project. (If any of the library projects need it they could get to it at compile time from your project)

Secondly, as for the actionbarsherlock library - I suggest you include this in your  project only (and if any of the library projects need it they could get to it at compile time from your project).